# How to connect to Azure DB that uses authentication type "Active Directory - Password" from SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis

Using Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT), I'm attempting to create a SSIS package that will send data to an Azure DB that uses the authentication method "Active Directory - Password".

What type of a connection can be used in SSIS to connect to an Azure DB that uses that type of authentication?  The only authentication options are "Windows Authentication" and "SQL Server Authentication" when using the "Native OLE DB\SQL Server Native Client 11.0" provider.  Is there a different provider that works with Azure DBs that use the authentication method "Active Directory - Password"?

[image]

Comment: OLE DB doesn't support it. ADO.Net does. You'll need to use an ADO.Net connection instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OLE DB doesn't support the "Active Directory - Password Authentication", but ADO.NET does.
[image]

Connecting to Azure SQL Server from SSIS using ‘OLEDB Connection manager’  is not a straight forward way, if you are to connect using your ‘Azure Account’ credentials.
The only way to connect using ‘Azure Account’ is by using ‘ADO.NET connection’ manager.

If you want to connect to Azure DB by using "Native OLE DB\SQL Server Native Client 11.0" provider, here is the tutorial maybe can help you:[Connecting to Azure SQL Server using OLEDB Connection from SSIS](https://rajeevpentyala.com/2018/08/23/step-by-step-connecting-to-azure-sql-server-using-oledb-connection-from-ssis/)