# Connect Azure DB using "Active Directory Password" from SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-active-directory, etl

Using visual studio 2022, i want to connect to Azure - Dynamics CRM Database by Active Directory Password.

I configured a new connection using ADO.NET option and when i click "test connection" it takes error. I can not figure it out, i can connect to database with same
credentials using SSMS

You can see below.

> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Invalid value for key 'authentication'.

[image: Connection Info]

[image: Error]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you able to connect using SSMS with the same options? Do you know exactly which SQL Server client library (and version) you're using?

Comment: Also, can you confirm that "Active Directory Password Authentication" is for **_Azure** Active Directory_? And does "_[Azure] Active Directory - Universal with MFA_" exist in the options list?

Comment: @dai, i added option as 3rd picture in my question. In SSIS there is no "Azure" option in login types for  ado.net component. Also i suppose, version of client is  "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"

Comment: SNAC 11 is obsolete and doesn't support many Azure SQL features ( https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/snac-lifecycle-explained/ba-p/385381 ) - you should be using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` or `.Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer` or `MSOLEDBSQL` (which is not the same thing as "_Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server_").

Comment: I see you have `.Net Providers\SqlClient Data Provider` selected - I'm assuming that corresponds to the older `System.Data.SqlClient` library instead of the current `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` - what other options do you see?

Comment: Since you're wanting to connect to Dynamics CRM have you considered trying an [OData Connection Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/odata-connection-manager) instead?

Comment: @dai, i attached options. There is "Microsoft Sql Client Data Provider" option which i tagged in red. I used that option and connection test is successfull. Yet, when i use ado-net source component with the connection manager, i can preview data. But when i execute package from visual studio i take error below;   **[ADO NET Source [2]] Error: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection 
{E022BF69-01BE-4CB8-A916-F5BD67A7DB43} with the following error message: "Could not create a managed connection manager.".**

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892500/how-to-connect-to-azure-db-that-uses-authentication-type-active-directory-pas) to connect sql server database with Active Directory - Password Authentication", you shouls use ADO.NET.

[image]

for more secure connection you should use Active directory Integrated authentication:

[image]

it may be useful to connect Azure db from SSIS.for more information you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1029316/ssis-connect-to-azure-sql-database-with-mfa).